# Correlation of two means, with known variance

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-r

I would like to estimate the correlation of two variables, `A` and `B`. For the first variable I have made three independent measurements at each point `x`, while for the second variable I have made two.

In R:

```
A = data.frame(x=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), replicate_id=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), value=c(1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6))
B = data.frame(x=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), replicate_id=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), value=c(0.9, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 0.3, 0.8))
```

Now a simple solution would of course be to just calculate a vector of mean values between all the replicates for each of the variables and then do a Pearson/Spearman correlation between the two. However, this would completely ignore the fact that I also know the variance of each value in each of these groups.

Is there a better solution that can take this into account?